# Proper laravel storage permissions

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.1

I have set my local laravel 5 storage folder to permissions `755` and to user `www-data`, as I use `apache2` on my machine. However I was getting blank screens instead of stack traces on errors so I changed the permissions to `777` which resolved the issue.

However I feel this is a (terrible) bandaid as really it is allowing *any* user to modify this directory with all permissions rather than the correct user with limited permissions. I don't know if this issue will affect the development or production server but granting those permissions in such a scenario is not an option.

How do I figure out *which* user (or group) actually needs permissions to use this directory for laravel logging so I can assign the directory to them and return the permissions back to 755?

I have tried

```
ps aux | egrep '(apache|httpd)'
```

but it shows that most processes are being run as `www-data`...

Comment: *How do I figure out which user (or group) actually needs permissions to use this directory for laravel* try `ls -l` in your project directory. it'll prints all directory with their respective owner. to change owner you could use `chown` - details on the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/chown). ah, to check user of a process use `ps u`. tbh this question mostly relevant to superuser.

Comment: You turned `error_reporting` & configured your `.htaccess` ?

Comment: Have you set the owner and permissions recursively? Because if you run `chmod 775 storage`, that will only change the permissions of the `storage` directory, but the files and folders inside will still have different permissions, the same applies to `chown`. Usually I run this to change the group `chgrp -R www-data storage` and this for permissions `chmod -R 775 storage`, this way you can have any user as owner (even `root`), but Apache can still write to storage files because the group is set to `www-data`. It would also help to post what errors you're getting if this does not help.

Comment: You can also check which user is writing to storage in the following way: while having `777` permissions, just access a route that returns a view and then check the `storage/framework/view` dir and see what's the owner of the view cache files inside with `ls -l`, since they are created by the HTTP server. If you're running a Debian based OS such as Ubuntu, the Apache user is most likely `www-data`.

Comment: Owner is `www-data` for `storage/framework/view`. Maybe it is a `htaccess` issue...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're on the right track with `ps aux | egrep '(apache|httpd)'`.

### Processes

Apache/httpd is started as user `root`, but then it spawns processes to handle incoming request as the user defined in it's configuration. That default user is usually either `www-data` or `apache`.

### Server OS

On **CentOS/RedHat** servers, you'll likely see processes being run as user/group `apache` (this is the default).

On **Debian/Ubuntu**, the default user set for the processes handling requests is `www-data`.

**This all assumes apache is using mod-php**. If you are using `php-fpm`, the use running PHP may be configured separately (altho it has the same defaults as apache in my experience).

### Permissions for `storage`

As it sounds like you know, the `storage` directory needs to be writable by the user or group (depending on permissions) running those processes.

### www-data?

It sounds like the result of `ps aux | egrep '(apache|httpd)'` was `www-data`, so it's likely, but not 100% definitive, that the directory needs to be writable by user/group `www-data` (either by setting it as the owner and ensuring owner has those permissions, or setting it via group permissions, or making it world-writable).

### A quick test

One easy way to tell is if you delete the log file / view cache files from the `storage` directory, and then make that directory world-writable.

Make some requests in Laravel that would re-generate those files, and then see what user/group is set on the new files.

That is one way to see what the user/group is set to of the process running PHP.

Comment: this got me sorted, `chown`ing it to the `www-data` user

Answer (score 2):

Are the folders in `storage` set to 755 too?

If not, you should change the permissions recursively by doing `chmod -R 755 storage`. Just take care when you use `chmod -R` because you could set the entire server to 755 by mistake.

Comment: Yes folders had permissions changed too, no difference.