# laravel5.1 - blade template not rendering

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I have tried all in this link :
[php laravel blade template not rendering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18939549/php-laravel-blade-template-not-rendering)

My codes are here.

my views/layouts/master.blade.php file contains

```
<html>
<body>
@section('sidebar')
This is the master sidebar.
@show

<div class="container">
@yield('content')
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

my views/child.blade.php file contains

```
@extends('layouts.master')

@section('content')
<p>This is my body content.</p>
@endsection
```

my route.php contains

```
Route::get('blade', function () {
return view('child');
});
```

from my browser I typed in :

```
http://localhost/larablog/public/blade
```

The output is a blank page.

I tried with non blade pages and it worked, I also passed normal variable to non blade pages which also worked. When I try with blade templating, the page seems to be blank always.

Please let me know where I went wrong.
Thanks.

Comment: to be sure, is there any file in `storage/framework/views/` ? and also, you get a blank page, even if you check the page source? also, did `return view(layouts.master)` had the same issue?

Comment: @tezla, no files found. A .gitignore file alone though.

Comment: @Tezla, yes my source is also blank.

Comment: hmm, do you use linux as a development environment? if so, it related to laravel permission issue.

Comment: @tezla, yes I tried the following
    `Route::get('/blade', function () {
    return view('layouts.master');
    });`

Comment: where do you have laravel installed or how? homestead? then you should be able to just to localhost/blade

Comment: @tezla, am on ubuntu 14.04 - permission issue? how is that ? can you brief ?

Comment: @Joost, laravel is on my local and NOT on homestead.

Comment: like this [so question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34175523/proper-laravel-storage-permissions)

Comment: @tezla, I changed **views/* folders and files** into **777** permission and got a blank page even in source too.

Comment: What do you get in http://localhost/larablog/blade ? (Withouth the 'public' part)

Comment: @Tezla, it worked !!!

Comment: glad it worked, it'd freak me out if laravel won't compile views and throw nothing to stacktrace.

Comment: @Tezla So what did work? Both you should make an answer and accept it...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As in the following link 
[Proper laravel storage permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34175523/proper-laravel-storage-permissions)

I had a permission issue at 
storage/framework/views folder.
I changed the folder permission to 777 and it all solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

May be Problem is with the routing

```
Route::get('/blade', function () {
  return view:('child');
});
```

Comment: sorry I forgot the mentions, I tried that too earlier and even now, it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

If you're running on apache make sure the web server has `write` permission to the `storage` directory.